# Play Framework with Internationalization test fails

Tags: scala, playframework, internationalization, playframework-2.6, twirl

When I run my Play Scala 2.6 app with Internationalization enabled, the page is rendered with all the content being picked up properly from my `messages.en` file.

But when I test my controller, one of the tests is failing when it checks the content of the page (`contentAsString(result) must include ("Welcome to Play")`).

The test fails because the content of the page is rendered as `label.welcome_to_play` instead of `Welcome to Play!`. This happens only when I render the index page from a new instance of the controller. When I test by rendering the page from the app or the router, the same test (contentAsString) is passing.

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

This is my `HomeController.scala`:

```
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents)
  extends AbstractController(cc) with I18nSupport {

  def index() = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }
}
```

And this is my `HomeControllerSpec.scala` test:

```
class HomeControllerSpec extends PlaySpec
  with GuiceOneAppPerTest
  with Injecting
  with Results {

  "Calling HomeController.index" should {

    "render the index page from a new instance of controller" in {
      val controller = new HomeController(stubControllerComponents())
      val result = controller.index().apply(FakeRequest(GET, "/"))

      status(result) mustBe OK
      contentType(result) mustBe Some("text/html")
      // THIS IS WHERE THE TEST FAILS. Content appears as "label.welcome_to_play"
      contentAsString(result) must include ("Welcome to Play")
    }

    "render the index page from the application" in {
      val controller = inject[HomeController]
      val home = controller.index().apply(FakeRequest(GET, "/"))

      status(home) mustBe OK
      contentType(home) mustBe Some("text/html")
      // WHILE THIS IS PASSING
      contentAsString(home) must include ("Welcome to Play")
    }

    "render the index page from the router" in {
      val request = FakeRequest(GET, "/")
      val home = route(app, request).get

      status(home) mustBe OK
      contentType(home) mustBe Some("text/html")
      // AND THIS IS PASSING
      contentAsString(home) must include ("Welcome to Play")
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my `index.scala.html` view:

```
@()(implicit messagesProvider: MessagesProvider)

@main(messagesProvider.messages("label.welcome_to_play")) {
  <h1>@messagesProvider.messages("label.welcome_to_play")</h1>
}
```

This is how my `messages.en` file looks like:

```
label.welcome_to_play = Welcome to Play!
```

I have the following configuration in my `conf` file:

```
play.i18n {
  langs = [ "en" , "lv ]
}
```

I tried renaming the file from `messages.en` to `messages` but it didn't help.

Does anyone know why the test fails? Why doesn't the messages file being used when rendering the page from a new instance of my controller? Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually ended up instantiating [DefaultMessagesApi](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApi) with a `testMessages` map as follows:

First, I created a `testMessages` map inside my `HomeControllerSpec`:

```
private val testMessages: Map[String, Map[String, String]] = Map(
  "en" -> Map(
    "label.welcome_to_play" -> "Welcome to Play!",
    "label.hello_world" -> "Hello world"
  )
)
```

This map contains only a short list of the labels that I want to test and is not a copy of the full `messages.en` file.

Then in the failing test, I create a new instance of the `HomeController` by overriding the `messagesApi`...

```
"render the index page from a new instance of controller" in {
  val controller = new HomeController(stubControllerComponents()) {
    override val messagesApi = new DefaultMessagesApi(testMessages)
  }
  val result: Future[Result] = controller.index().apply(FakeRequest(GET, "/"))

  status(result) mustBe OK
  contentType(result) mustBe Some("text/html")
  contentAsString(result) must include ("Welcome to Play")
}
```

... and the test is passing.

I acknowledge that this approach causes some duplication (message labels both inside the `messages.en` file and the Spec) but for small tests with not many messages to test, I think it's an acceptable solution.

Comment: Is it all the changes we need in tests ? I did similarly and but I get ` request.messages` as NULL in the Controller

Answer (score 0):

The `MessagesApi` is provided by the `ControllerComponents` and will contain the list of messages and their translation.

When you use `stubControllerComponents` this [will create](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/c038bc147b03285a1de7acc50037e1e7f438bedf/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Helpers.scala#L591) a `MessagesApi` object with [no messages](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/c038bc147b03285a1de7acc50037e1e7f438bedf/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Helpers.scala#L509) in it.

If you want your translated messages, you need to use an other `ControllerComponents`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing you mentioned about the empty `MessageApi` pointed me to the right direction. I ended up instantiating `DefaultMessagesApi` as you can see from the answer that I posted.